# How do find the general solution to this system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, biology

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dI_n}{dt} &= 2(1-p) I_n - I_n + 2(1-p) I_v \\
\frac{dI_v}{dt} &= 2p I_v - 3 I_v + 2p I_n
\end{align}
$$

I tried to find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors for this matrix where matrix A is:

$$
A = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1-p & 2(1-p) \\
2p &  2p-3
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

From this matrix, I ended up with the characteristic equation of

$$λ^2+λ(2-p)+2p^2+p-3=0$$

When I used the quadratic equation to solve for the eigenvalues, it becomes too complex an I don't know how to get a "clean" value.

Is there another way of solving for the general solution? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Is $I_n$ a function ($I_n: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$), not the identity matrix?

Comment: Note: The matrix should have $a_{11} = 1 - 2p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mvw is correct, the matrix $A$ should be.

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1-2p&2-2p\\
2p&2p-3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-1+2\sqrt{1-p}$ and $\lambda_2=-1-2\sqrt{1-p}$. With corresponding eigenvectors:
$$
{\bf v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{2(p-1)}{-2+2\sqrt{1-p}+2p}\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
{\bf v_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{2(p-1)}{-2-2\sqrt{1-p}+2p}\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

With general solution (in eigenvalues are real and distinct):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I_n(t)\\
I_v(t)
\end{bmatrix}
=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}{\bf v_1}+c_2e^{\lambda_2t}{\bf v_2}
$$

To move forward from here we need more info like an initial condition and some idea of the value of $p$. If $p=1$ you will not get two linearly independent eigenvectors from $\lambda=-1$, if $p>1$ you will have complex eigenvalues...

Also note that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors were computed with maple. I have not verified them.